# PHP Type hinting to allow Array or ArrayAccess

Tags: php, type-hinting, union-types, arrayaccess

Is it possible to allow an Array or an object that implements ArrayAccess?

For example:

```
class Config implements ArrayAccess {
    ...
}

class I_Use_A_Config
{
    public function __construct(Array $test)
    ...
}
```

I want to be able to pass in either an Array or ArrayAccess.

Is there a clean way to do this other than manually checking the parameter type?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, there is no "clean" way of doing it.

The `array` type is a *primitive type*. Objects that implement the `ArrayAccess` interface are based on classes, also known as a *composite type*. There is no type-hint that encompasses both.

Since you are using the `ArrayAccess` as an array you could just cast it. For example:

```
$config = new Config;
$lol = new I_Use_A_Config( (array) $config);
```

If that is not an option (you want to use the `Config` object as it is) then just remove the type-hint and check that it is either an array or an `ArrayAccess`. I know you wanted to avoid that but it is not a big deal. It is just a few lines and, when all is said and done, inconsequential.

Comment: Not the answer I hoped for but casting to an array is actually a nice idea. Thanks

Comment: This is a bad practice, a client should not do what the library can do.

Comment: Casting an object to array does not care whether ArrayAccess is implemented or not. AFAIK the only thing that will change the casting functionality is subclassing the ArrayObject class. Hopefully https://wiki.php.net/rfc/union_types makes it in someday (not related to casting obviously, but to the OP's question) ;)

Comment: this is sooo sad :(

Comment: This answer may not satisfy all cases. For example, I have an ArrayIterator which calls getters instead of attributes, if the function which receives the array tries to access to a getter without attribute it will not find it. I would remove the typehint in this case and perform a manual check with a `$test instanceof ArrayAccess or is_array($test)`

Comment: I rather wish I could cast an `array` to `ArrayAccess`...

Answer (score 6):

**PHP 8.0+**

You can use union of `array` and `ArrayAccess`.

```
class I_Use_A_Config
{
    public function __construct(array|ArrayAccess $test)
    ...
}
```

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php#language.types.declarations.union
- https://wiki.php.net/rfc/union_types